# Android: How to use ColorMatrix to achieve the same effect of ImageView.setAlpha()

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am using GridView to display more that thirty images (5 images in a column). I found that when I use ImageView.setAlpha() function in the main Thread, the fluidity of GridView scrolling becomes bad.

Therefore, I want to use ColorMatrix to produce the same effect of function setAlpha(). Here is my code,

```
Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
Bitmap mutableBitmap = resultBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
// ColorMatrix
float[] colorMatrix = new float[] {
          1, 0, 0, 0, 0, //red
          0, 1, 0, 0, 0, //green
          0, 0, 1, 0, 0, //blue
          0, 0, 0, A, 0  //alpha
};
colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.restore();
```

I read several code saying that the above code can produce the same function. I have tried several values of A. However, I can not find the desired effect.

When A is 1, the same picture.
When A is 0, becomes all black.
When A is 0.5, becomes darker. Theorectically speaking, it should become lighter.

Do you know the problem??